# Phidget lib cross compiling

Tags: linux

I try to cross compile Phidget driver for ARM9 board, but in Phidget webpage, the description is:
~/phidget_libraries $> ./configure --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-gnueabi

I do not use the standard arm-linux-gnueabi tool, but aother arm-gnueabi-bovine tool, how can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the host variable with the toolchain you are using. So the configure should be run as
~/phidget_libraries $> ./configure --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-gnueabi-bovine

Make sure you have added the toolchain path to the path variable($PATH)

export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH:$PATH